# Using nested properties from object in Vuex store inside a template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Assuming that I have a getter for my `Vuex.Store` that returns an object with many properties and I want to use this object in a component. Is there any way to do something similar to this:

```
<div v-bind="$store.getters['x/y']">
   <p>{{scopedObject.prop1}}</p>
</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div>
   <p>{{$store.state.x.data.y.prop1}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm asking if I can scope objects to blocks.

The simple answer is *no*.

You could define a [`computed` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) which returns the nested object.

```
computed: {
    scopedObject() {
        return this.$store.getters['x/y'];
    }
}
```

In fact, this is where [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) is meant to be used.

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: mapGetters({ scopedObject: 'x/y' }),
}
```

Then, the template would simply be

```
<div>
   <p>{{scopedObject.prop1}}</p>
</div>
```

If you really want to make a new *scope*, define a new component which will only define the section of the template you want it to use.

A simple `prop` could be used, so it doesn't need to know about the store.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{scopedObject.prop1}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            scopedObject: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Then, in the parent:

```
<template>
    <scoped-component :scoped-object="$store.getters['x/y']"><scoped-component>
</template>
```

Comment: This doesn't make any difference from calling '$store.getters['x/y'].prop1'. So your answer is pointless.

Comment: I'm asking if I can scope objects to blocks.

Comment: @Arrrr the simple answer is no. I updated my answer to reflect that and added another alternative.

Comment: @Arrrr Just so you know, it's not me who downvoted you.

Comment: I'm not trying to take revenge :D, on the other hand, I really appreciate your help. This is what I had in mind in the first place but if there isn't any better way, have no choice but to stick to it.

Comment: @Arrrr Vue makes it really easy to split into components (as small as they can be) and I think we should embrace that ;)